# Can't install pyexiv2 in conda env on macbook

Tags: anaconda, conda, pyexiv2

I want to install pyexiv2 in a conda environment on a macbook. I tried a conda install of pyexiv2 and of python-pyexiv2 (as it was called when I successfully installed it on ubuntu).

pyexiv2:

```
(py27) IEC02R5A6DG8WP:pythonScripts mdev0002$ conda install pyexiv2
Fetching package metadata ...........

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - pyexiv
```

python-pyexiv2:

```
(py27) IEC02R5A6DG8WP:pythonScripts mdev0002$ conda install python-pyexiv2
Fetching package metadata ...........

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

  - python-pyexiv2
```

I then tried the pip from conda but that yielded no results either

```
(py27) IEC02R5A6DG8WP:pythonScripts mdev0002$ pip install python-pyexiv2
Collecting python-pyexiv2
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-pyexiv2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-pyexiv2
(py27) IEC02R5A6DG8WP:pythonScripts mdev0002$ pip install pyexiv2
Collecting pyexiv2
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyexiv2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyexiv2
(py27) IEC02R5A6DG8WP:pythonScripts mdev0002$
```

I found documentation that says this python package can be installed via homebrew on the mac (http://macappstore.org/pyexiv2/) but how can I get this into a conda env?

Answer (score 0):

pyexiv2 is unfortunately not available on PyPI. If your code is easy to port into Python 3, I'd recommend [py3exiv2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py3exiv2/) which is available on PyPI. So you can just run `pip install py3exiv2`

Comment: You can also use pexif in Python 2.7